# MVVM on Android with DataBinding or RxJava?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, rx-java, android-databinding

I am building an Android app and am fairly new to both MVVM and data binding concepts on Android.

I have read at a few places ( like [here](https://www.codevate.com/blog/13-better-android-software-development-mvvm-with-rxjava)) that both RxJava and Google's [DataBinding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) can be used for implementing MVVM pattern.

I went through the official Android documentation for DataBinding and am going through [a project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-databinding) referenced by Google on Mvvm using DataBinding. However, I have no idea how RxJava works as of yet, which might be obvious from the question.

My question is, keeping in mind the long term goals of extending my app, is it worth investing effort in learning RxJava? Or does DataBinding suffice as a complete substitute for it? I don't know RxJava at all but by reading about it online gives me the impression that it can solve a wide range of problems.

I do not mind investing time in learning RxJava but is it worth the effort than simply using Google's DataBinding (which I have some sort of grasp on)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RxJava is a completely different concept than DataBinding. It's more of a way of handling concurrency than it is about binding data. I 100% think it's worth learning. The Android community has embraced it with open arms.

Shameless plug: I compiled a list of RxJava resources awhile back - http://gregloesch.com/dev/2014/10/20/resources-for-learning-rxjava-android.html

Comment: But the article I referred to and elsewhere on the internet I read that it can be used for data binding for MVVM purposes. That is what confused me.

Comment: @Raymond232 you could set it up to do data binding of sorts. Rx makes your code "reactive", so you could structure things so that a change in something like a model would notify all subscribers (say the view is a subscriber) that a change was made.

Comment: Thanks. On a side note, would you think it will be alright to just use Google's data binding library for MVVM right now and put learning RxJava on hold for now? Because I went through the few links you have mentioned in your blog and I realized that to make appropriate use of RxJava I will need to devote quite some time to understand it.

Comment: @raymond yeah, perfectly fine! Do what makes sense for you/your team right now. If you have the capacity, maybe give it another go later. And if you do, start small with just network calls or something similar.